# How to make many tuples with variable name

Tags: python, string, list, variables, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
somelist = ['apple','grapes','wood']
```

but somelist may be either 3 items in length or even 20 items in length

I want to make a tuple for each of those items like:

```
tup1 = ('apple')
tup2 = ('grapes')
....
tup(i) = ('item')
```

but how do I make the variable name... "variable" ?

Comment: If you're trying to modify the variable names, you probably want to use a list (which can grow or shrink as you need it).

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: "Don't." Don't put data in your variable names.

You already have something nearly identical to what you've asked for:

```
somelist[1] == 'apple'
```

You can get even closer by create a list of tuples:

```
tup = [ (item,) for item in somelist ]

# Now tup[1] == ('grapes',)
```

Finally, if you absolutely must create variables, use `setattr`:

```
for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
    setattr(self, 'tup%d'%i, (item,))

# Now self.tup1 == ('grapes',)
```